# Can't go to Home page after the user logged in - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, formsauthentication

I'm working with ASP.Net application and I have followed this tutorial [HERE](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Login-Form-example-in-ASPNet.aspx) to create a login page but whenever I tried to login it return to the `Seller_login.aspx` page not to `Home.aspx page`! I think the login process works fine because after I logged in the browser asked me if I want to remember my username and password! But the only problem with the home page! Please any help?

`web.config` code :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/Seller_Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

`Seller_login.aspx.cs` code:

```
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 0;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Seller_Validate_User"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
        }
        switch (userId)
        {
            case -1:
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                break;
            case -2:
                Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                break;
            default:
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                break;
          }
     }
}
```

`Home.aspx.cs` code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which page are you initially navigating to? It will send you to that before the default.

Comment: the `Seller_login.aspx`

Comment: It looks like you don't have any code to change the value of the variable `Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` of `Home.aspx.cs` in your validation method. Where is that happening?

Comment: @kailanjian yes i don't have .. what do you mean by where's that happening?

Comment: If that variable is false you will redirect to the login page every time you load the page. You should set it to true somewhere.